# How to block Landscape Orientation mode in ONSEN-UI?

Tags: cordova, orientation, onsen-ui, landscape-portrait

I am developing a ONSEN Application, in which I want to allow only a Portrait mode for the device and want to set off the Landscape mode. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onsen UI doesn't provide a function to disable landscape mode, because this functionality is platform dependent. What you can do is, first, detecting the orientation with `ons.orientation`, followed by the platform with `ons.platform`, and apply the default platform instructions to block the landscape mode.

An easier solution could be just to rotate the view back to portrait, after it has been rotated in landscape.

```js
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function ()
{
    if (window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth)
    {
        document.getElementsByTagName('body').style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
    }
});
```

Comment: Ya...Actually I got the solution with only one line of code! Just add <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" /> in config.xml...! And thanks a lot bro!

Comment: What if one needs to have Portrait on Phones and Landscape on Tablets. How to achieve that. I am able to restrict to Portrait by changing the Orientation in the config.xml file.